# Why do pygame drawings only appear after the window is dragged off screen?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am attempting to draw a chess board (the current code has nothing to do with chess boards, as I'm trying to debug my issue), and I'm running into an interesting issue with pygame.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

window_width = 400
window_height = 400
display_window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))

. . . 

def chess_game():
    playing = True
    while playing:
        clock.tick(30)
        # chess_board.draw()
        pygame.draw.rect(display_window, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, window_width, window_height))
        pygame.draw.circle(display_window, (0, 255, 0), (100, 100), 20)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                playing = False
                pygame.quit()
                break

chess_game()
```

So when I run this code, I am expecting to get a red window with a green circle. Instead, I get a black screen. The strange thing I'm running into, however, is that if I drag the window off the screen (so that a portion of the window is outside of my desktop window), the portion of the window that is outside my desktop will be drawn correctly. See the image below.
[image]

As you can see, the red background and the circle are there, they just aren't visible unless I drag the window off the screen.

I don't think it's a pygame problem, as I built an actually functional program using similar code already. If this helps at all, I'm on a Windows 10 laptop using PyCharm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call

```
pygame.display.update()
```

on each frame. Dragging the window has the side effect of ensuring the newly "revealed" pixels are updated.